# Deserialize String to MacAddr6 in toml file

Tags: rust, deserialization, toml

I have a toml file with pairs id and mac like this:

```
[[component]]
id = 1
mac = "d4:d7:04:c9:85:a4"
[[component]]
id = 3
mac = "3c:21:ee:b4:0d:ab"
[[component]]
id = 6
mac = "ea:f3:23:8c:b8:c1"
```

The goal is to deserialize this file to a Vec of this `struct` (`MacAddr6` belongs to the `macaddr` crate:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Component {
    pub id: u16,
    pub mac: MacAddr6,
}
```

When I try to deserialize, this error is shown:

> inner: TomlError { message: "invalid type: string
> "d4:d7:04:c9:85:a4", expected an array of length 6"

If I change `MacAddr6` to `String` in the struct definition and everything worked fine, so I have a workaround. Nevertheless, since `MacAddr6` implements `serde::Deserialize` and `core::str::FromStr` I was expecting to retrieve the full struct in one time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can always "cheat" a bit here and implement an intermediate `ComponentSerializeProxy` that is all `String` types, and then add on a `TryInto<Component>` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Assuming things for no reason? `MacAddr6` derives `Deserializable` and is defined like this:

```
pub struct MacAddr6([u8; 6]);
```

In most serialization schemes, that means it's going to be encoded to and decoded from a 6-wide array of integers. Not a string.

`FromStr` does not enter the equation either, serde [has no support for it](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/908), and even if it did you'd need to tell serde to use it, especially since `MacAddr6` has a `Deserialize` (so there would be no way for serde to provide a default implementation even if it were possible).

What you can do is either hand-roll this conversion via a custom deserialization function (and [the `deserialize_with` attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with)) or use [the relevant helper from serde_with](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.DisplayFromStr.html).

Comment: serde_with did the trick: use `#[serde_as]` in the struct and  `#[serde_as(as = "DisplayFromStr")]` in the `mac` field. Thank you.